# doctrine generate entities outside of public schema

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I see I can [set the schema](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L431) as an option in the Entity itself but is there an option to generate entities outside of the Public Schema?

Here is what works for the Public Schema

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

maybe something like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml schema=Foo  ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

FYI we use PostgreSQL 8.x & 9.x as our database & Symfony 2.1.3 if that matters

UPDATE:

- https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Builder/ClassMetadataBuilder.php

I think this is what I'm looking for but need a way to set the schema array value:

```
/**
 * Sets the table name.
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return ClassMetadataBuilder
 */
public function setTable($name)
{
    $this->cm->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => $name));

    return $this;
}
```

UPDATE #2

I think it might be possible to set this in the connection configuration

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Original Config

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: my_database
      connections:
        my_database:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   bar
          user:     foo_user
          password: foo_pass
          charset:  UTF8
```

set the schema:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: my_database
      connections:
        my_database:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   bar/Foo
          user:     foo_user
          password: foo_pass
          charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: The solution in UPDATE #2 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, if you:

```
ALTER USER foo_user SET search_path=foo;
```

Then everything not otherwise specified will be created in schema foo.  If you can't solve it in Doctrine, you can solve it in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I use Symfony 3 and I got 3 different schemas. To generate entities I use `--filter` option e.g:

```
./bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force --filter="Schema_name." MyBundle xml
```

Then execute other commands to generate entities. For me work perfectly

Edit.
Last thing, schema name must begin at upper case